# How do I export call history from tc.db aka truecaller. database to regular phone app

Tags: android, database, sqlite, export, root

I have a situation where my android phone rebooted and  pretty much  truncated  my  `call history & contacts`. I immediately  set  `extundelete & ext4magic`  (  these were `linked` to   `sdext2  ext4` `partition` .   `Internal data`  is `f2fs` where your chances for deleted `data recovery` are pretty much hosed ) to work but there wasnt any chance of recovering .  I could'nt find the version of data I was looking for . But My `call history` is there in `Truecaller`. How do I  export call history from  `Trucaller` in a format where I can import it back to   Regular phone app ( i.e. regular `contacts app`).

Env : `Android 10  V 29.  Rooted.`
Here is what I have in my Truecaller data directory.

```
 ///# ll /data/sdext2/data/com.truecaller/databases/{*.db,*shm}                                                                      
-rw-rw---- 1 u0_a431 u0_a431          24576 2023-07-24 10:03 /data/sdext2/data/com.truecaller/databases/AdWatchDatabase_Impl.db
-rw-rw---- 1 u0_a431 u0_a431          32768 2023-08-22 15:43 /data/sdext2/data/com.truecaller/databases/AdWatchDatabase_Impl.db-shm
-rwxrwxr-x 1 u0_a431 u0_a431          69632 2023-03-16 17:52 /data/sdext2/data/com.truecaller/databases/adCampaigns.db
-rw-rw---- 1 u0_a431 u0_a431          28672 2023-03-16 18:16 /data/sdext2/data/com.truecaller/databases/ads.db
-rw-rw---- 1 u0_a431 u0_a431          49152 2023-08-22 16:05 /data/sdext2/data/com.truecaller/databases/analytics.db
-rw-rw---- 1 u0_a431 u0_a431          32768 2023-08-22 16:06 /data/sdext2/data/com.truecaller/databases/analytics.db-shm
-rw-rw---- 1 u0_a431 u0_a431          32768 2023-08-21 09:26 /data/sdext2/data/com.truecaller/databases/bizCallSurveyDatabase-shm
-rw------- 1 u0_a431 u0_a431          32768 2023-07-04 19:11 /data/sdext2/data/com.truecaller/databases/callDeclineMessages-shm
-rw-rw---- 1 u0_a431 u0_a431          98304 2023-08-21 11:03 /data/sdext2/data/com.truecaller/databases/calling-cache.db
-rw-rw---- 1 u0_a431 u0_a431          32768 2023-08-22 15:59 /data/sdext2/data/com.truecaller/databases/calling-cache.db-shm
-rwxrwxr-x 1 u0_a431 u0_a431          32768 2023-05-04 11:03 /data/sdext2/data/com.truecaller/databases/contactFeedbackDb-shm
-rw-rw---- 1 u0_a431 u0_a431          32768 2023-08-22 16:06 /data/sdext2/data/com.truecaller/databases/contextCallDb-shm
-rw-rw---- 1 u0_a431 u0_a431          32768 2023-08-22 16:04 /data/sdext2/data/com.truecaller/databases/dialer-shm
-rwxrwxr-x 1 u0_a431 u0_a431_cache   159744 2023-06-23 17:43 /data/sdext2/data/com.truecaller/databases/emojis.db
-rwxrwxr-x 1 u0_a431 u0_a431          32768 2023-06-23 17:43 /data/sdext2/data/com.truecaller/databases/emojis.db-shm
-rw-rw---- 1 u0_a431 u0_a431         262144 2023-08-22 16:06 /data/sdext2/data/com.truecaller/databases/exoplayer_internal.db
-rwxrwxr-x 1 u0_a431 u0_a431          32768 2023-03-16 17:54 /data/sdext2/data/com.truecaller/databases/flashSdkDb-shm
-rw-rw---- 1 u0_a431 u0_a431          86016 2023-03-18 17:20 /data/sdext2/data/com.truecaller/databases/freshchat.db
-rw-rw---- 1 u0_a431 u0_a431          16384 2023-08-22 16:06 /data/sdext2/data/com.truecaller/databases/google_app_measurement_local.db
-rw-rw---- 1 u0_a431 u0_a431        1327104 2023-08-19 08:33 /data/sdext2/data/com.truecaller/databases/insights.db
-rw-rw---- 1 u0_a431 u0_a431          32768 2023-08-22 14:13 /data/sdext2/data/com.truecaller/databases/insights.db-shm
-rw-rw---- 1 u0_a431 u0_a431          49152 2023-08-05 10:45 /data/sdext2/data/com.truecaller/databases/installed_apps.db
-rw-rw---- 1 u0_a431 u0_a431          32768 2023-08-21 06:46 /data/sdext2/data/com.truecaller/databases/installed_apps.db-shm
-rw-rw---- 1 u0_a431 u0_a431          32768 2023-08-22 13:28 /data/sdext2/data/com.truecaller/databases/joint_worker_analytics-shm
-rw-rw---- 1 u0_a431 u0_a431          32768 2023-08-22 06:56 /data/sdext2/data/com.truecaller/databases/searchWarningsDb-shm
-rw-rw---- 1 u0_a431 u0_a431           4096 2023-03-16 18:01 /data/sdext2/data/com.truecaller/databases/spamcategories.db
-rw-rw---- 1 u0_a431 u0_a431          32768 2023-08-22 14:17 /data/sdext2/data/com.truecaller/databases/spamcategories.db-shm
-rw-rw---- 1 u0_a431 u0_a431          32768 2023-08-22 16:05 /data/sdext2/data/com.truecaller/databases/surveysDb-shm
-rw-rw---- 1 u0_a431 u0_a431         110592 2023-08-18 22:44 /data/sdext2/data/com.truecaller/databases/tags.db
-rw-rw---- 1 u0_a431 u0_a431       66469888 2023-08-22 16:08 /data/sdext2/data/com.truecaller/databases/tc.db
-rw-rw---- 1 u0_a431 u0_a431          32768 2023-08-22 16:08 /data/sdext2/data/com.truecaller/databases/tc.db-shm
-rw-rw---- 1 u0_a431 u0_a431          65536 2023-08-22 14:17 /data/sdext2/data/com.truecaller/databases/tc_ads.db
-rw-rw---- 1 u0_a431 u0_a431          32768 2023-08-22 16:06 /data/sdext2/data/com.truecaller/databases/tc_ads.db-shm
-rw-rw---- 1 u0_a431 u0_a431          32768 2023-08-21 06:46 /data/sdext2/data/com.truecaller/databases/telecom_operator_data_db-shm
-rw-rw---- 1 u0_a431 u0_a431          32768 2023-08-22 16:06 /data/sdext2/data/com.truecaller/databases/videoCallerIdDb-shm
-rw-rw---- 1 u0_a431 u0_a431          32768 2023-08-22 16:06 /data/sdext2/data/com.truecaller/databases/voipDb-shm
-rw-rw---- 1 u0_a431 u0_a431          32768 2023-08-22 13:02 /data/sdext2/data/com.truecaller/databases/work_actions-shm
```